# consecutive analogRead()

Tags: analogread

Has anyone noticed that if calling `analogRead()` in a consecutive way that the value drops by a bit as opposed to just doing a single read?

And is this to be expected?

I am using a Seeeduino XIAO.

Comment: You need a short delay between analog reads, more about it here: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-little-delay-needed-after-analogRead-in-Arduino

Comment: @Nino Thank you. That would explain it! _(Add it as answer and I mark it as solution.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a short delay between analog reads due to the time it takes to complete a reliable ADC reading. In depth technical explanations can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-little-delay-needed-after-analogRead-in-Arduino), note that it refers to AVR architecture.